# The Sims 2: Please insert the correct CD-ROM

Tags: technical-issues, windows-10, the-sims-2

I've been buying and playing The Sims games since the early 2000s. A couple years ago, when I realized that my future computers might not have disc drives (and The Sims 1 and 2 aren't sold digitally), I ripped all these to ISO files so I could continue to play them.

Today, I tried to re-install [The Sims 2 Special DVD Edition](http://sims.wikia.com/wiki/The_Sims_2_Special_DVD_Edition#Editions) on my new computer using these ISOs. The installation went great, even accepting the code I still had on my physical box! However, when I went to play it (keeping the virtual disc in the virtual `D:` drive), it gave me this error:

[image: A dialog box with the title "Cannot locate the CD-ROM" and message "Please insert the correct CD-ROM, select OK and restart the application", with only an "OK" and close option.]

To my horror, when I tried to insert the physical disc (thankfully I have a Blu-Ray Drive on this computer), it couldn't be read; it seems that it's too scratched over time.

**So my physical disc can't be read and the game won't see my ISO rip of that disc. What can I do do get the game to run?**

---

My setup:

- Windows 10 Pro (x64)
- Virtual DVD drive labeled `D:`
- Physical BD drive labeled `E:`
- 32GB of DDR4 RAM across 4 sticks
- Xeon E5 v3  —  12 x 3.50 GHz cores (virtualized from 6)

Comment: Sadly, we can't really give you any workarounds; anything we suggest could be considered piracy; if the disk doesn't work, the only valid option we can tell you is to buy it again.

Comment: @Frank and I might just do that; I really think they deserve it after all the value I've gotten from the game. Still, I'm worried that after I do this it still won't recognize its disc...

Comment: Oh.  It might not actually be your disk.  Sims 2 uses Securom, and Windows 10 disables that DRM, due to how unsafe it is.  It could just be straight up incompatible with Windows 10.

Comment: Hm... I might buy a secondary drive and install Windows 7 on it to play older games like this.

Comment: @ИвоНедев We can't advocate that here.  We cannot support piracy in any sense whatsoever.

Comment: @Supuhstar OR just install a Virtual Box and then run Windows 7 in that.

Comment: @ИвоНедев eh, maybe. That tends to be much slower, though.

Comment: Allocate some more cores and ram to the vm from the settings, should be fine for sims2

Comment: @ИвоНедев perhaps. It's the GPU I'm concerned about. Anyway, I'll try that and get back.

Comment: I have installed WIndows 7, and I successfully installed The Sims 2 on that. It still gives me the same error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I legitimately bought these games, I went to EA technical support and told them everything I told here. They asked for my product key, and I gave it.

They proceeded to place [The Sims 2 Ultimate Collection](http://sims.wikia.com/wiki/Compilations_of_The_Sims_2#The_Sims_2:_Ultimate_Collection) in my Origin account. Upon downloading this, I was easily able to run The Sims 2 and all of its expansion packs, stuff packs, and patches.

There are then two known issues remaining: The resolution is locked at 800x600, and Sim shadows indoors are large black rectangles. The good news is that these are [well-known](https://www.google.com/search?q=the+sims+2+resolution+fix) and [easily fixed](https://www.google.com/search?q=sims+2+black+rectangle+under+sim).

**tl;dr If you have a legitimate copy of The Sims 2 (expansion packs or not), tell EA and they will give you Ultimate Collection, which runs easily on modern computers.**